# Create .desktop file for Eclipse CDT Oxygen

Tags: permissions, launcher, eclipse

I have trouble creating a .desktop file for Eclipse CDT because of file permission issues.

I installed Eclipse CDT Oxygen using the standard installer from the Eclipse website [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/oxygen/R/eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz).

I selected `/opt` as the installation location, so the full installation file path with the default subpath is `/opt/eclipse/cpp-oxygen/eclipse`.

I created an `eclipse.desktop` file with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse
Type=Application
Exec=/opt/eclipse/cpp-oxygen/eclipse/eclipse
Icon=/opt/eclipse/cpp-oxygen/eclipse/icon.xpm
Terminal=false
```

If I try to launch Eclipse using this `.desktop` file, I get the following error message:

> "The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its  companion
>   shared library."

The reason is that the permission is denied to access some directory.

Now if I launch Eclipse as a super user from the terminal, it launches just fine:

```
sudo /opt/eclipse/cpp-oxygen/eclipse/eclipse
```

How can I fix the `.desktop` file?

As per the suggestion in the comments I ran the following commands in the terminal and got the following output:

```
cd / && /opt/eclipse/cpp-oxygen/eclipse/eclipse
```

and

```
cd /opt/eclipse/cpp-oxygen/eclipse && ./eclipse
```

both return this same output:

```
/root/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.500.v20170531-1133: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

and a pop-up dialog with the error message quoted above.

This is the content of `/opt/eclipse/cpp-oxygen/eclipse/eclipse.ini`:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
/root/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.500.v20170531-1133
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph$
```

I guess that's where the problem lies. How should I change the content?

Comment: Could you please try to run both `cd / && /opt/eclipse/cpp-oxygen/eclipse/eclipse` and `cd /opt/eclipse/cpp-oxygen/eclipse && ./eclipse` from a terminal and [edit] your question to include their output? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster thanks a lot for chiming in! I ran both commands and edited my question above. What do you think? Thanks a lot!

Comment: For whatever reason the Eclipse installation appears to believe that it's plug-in directory should be `/root/.p2`. What's the value of the environment variable `ECLIPSE_HOME` and what's the content of `/opt/eclipse/cpp-oxygen/eclipse/eclipse.ini` (if any)? Could you please try to launch Eclipse with a new, empty workspace (to rule out misconfiguration on that end)?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help @DavidFoerster! I edited my question again to include the content of `eclipse.ini`. That's probably where the problem is? I couldn't find an environment variable `ECLIPSE_HOME`. The command `printenv ECLIPSE_HOME` returns nothing and if I enter just `printenv` or `set`, the resulting lists contain no such variable. Should it be there? Again, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I think you need to remove the entry `--launcher.library` and the subsequent entry `/root/.p2/pool/plugins` from `eclipse.ini`. See https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Launcher#Command_line_arguments. Could you please confirm whether this helps?

Comment: @DavidFoerster removing the launcher library argument didn't work unfortunately, the result is that the launcher complains that it cannot locate its shared companion library. I tried something else: I simply copied the entire library located at `/root/.p2` to `/opt/eclipse/cpp-oxygen/eclipse and changed the path in `eclipse.ini` and all other paths I could find in other files accordingly. But that didn't work either: This time I got an unspecific error that there was "a problem".

Comment: I'm starting to think I will have to uninstall the whole thing and try to see if there are any options I can set differently in the installer so that it doesn't put the shared library into `/root/`. Unless you have other ideas :/. Thanks so much that you keep helping and suggesting things, I really appreciate it!